# MOSS 2007 Anonymous Posting

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2007

I want to create a method for users to post comments (to a blog?) in Sharepoint anonymously.

This would preferably be within an existing - authenticated - site.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of great blog posts that directly relate to this. Reza Alirezaei describes the [things to consider](http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/?p=498) as well as how to do it. Tyler DeNormandie [explains how to do](https://mysite.uchicago.edu/personal/bsdad_tdenormandie/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2) exactly your scenario.